# Google Map Marker not showing in Blackberry app

Tags: google-maps, blackberry

I wrote a javascript code similar to the code in this sample.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple

It is supposed to render a Google map with markers on it.

It is working perfectly on all browsers.

But when I open it in Blackberry browser - it does not show any markers although the map load successfully.

Can you help in this?

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share some more information?

Comment: Which BlackBerry device?  Which operating system?

Comment: I'm having the same problem using a BB Z10.

The generated html and JS workes fine in desktop browsers and also on android phones.

On the BB it usually draws just the map or even a blank window in random order. Several refreshes will get the proper results.

My js also does a fit to bounds and I noticed when it only draws the map it is still at the inial zoom level which kinda makes sense if there are no markers.

Comment: Z10 here, same issue. Try enabling the Web Inspector... it didn't help me, but who knows. http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/getting_started_webinsp_microsite_1987477_11.html